# Completeness of weighted powers

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am confused on a definition in Petex Lax’s book on Functional Analysis.

He writes:

> Let $w(t)$ be a given positive function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ that decays exponentially as $|t|\rightarrow 0$:
> $$0<w(t)<ae^{-c|t|}, c>0.$$

My question is exactly on whether or not $w$ is a continuous function since I can’t understand the following parts in the book where $w$ is used.

He continues:

> Denote by *C* the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at $\infty$:
> $$\lim_{|t|\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=0.$$
> *C* is a Banach space under the maximum norm. (This is clear to me)
>
> Theorem: The functions $t^nw(t)$ belong to *C*; their closed linear span is all of *C*.

The theorem is proved through the spanning criterion and basic properties of analytic functions to show that $w(t)e^{i\zeta t}$, for $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$, is in the closed span of $t^nw(t)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Then Weierstrass aproximation theorem on periodic functions to argue that $wh$ is in the closed span of $we^{i\zeta t}$ for $h$ periodic function. Then finishes by saying that $y$ is in the closed span of $wh$ for $y$ a continuous function of compact support. And since $y$ is dense in *C*, the proof is complete.

While writing this, I came up with a seemingly good reason: $w$ does not need to be continuous and it would be fine due to $(C,|\cdot|_{\max})$ being complete since by construction continuous functions would be in this Banach space, so we could by completeness show that a function, possibly with uncountable many discontinuities, would be in the Banach space, while not ignoring the limit property. Would this be a valid answer to my confusion on $w$?

Comment: If $w$ was not continuous then $t^nw(t)$ would not be continuous either, so not part of $C$. Considering this I guess $w$ is assumed to be continuous.

Comment: Couldn't the book be referring to C as a Banach space and not C the set of continuous functions? At the end of the theorem, the book has: "The functions $y$ of compact support are dense in C, and the proof is complete.", and unless I'm wrong, C as the closure of this dense subset doesn't make sense without a metric being involved @Lazy